# Swift if statement being re-executed when button title updated

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this very simple code, the button is set to the title "Title1" in IB

```
@IBAction func changeTitle(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    if (button.titleLabel == "Title1") {
        button.setTitle("Title2", forState: .Normal)

    } else {
        button.setTitle("Title1", forState: .Normal)
    }

}
```

So what's happening is that the first condition in the if statement gets executed, then the line of code updating the title of the button is hit, where then it goes back to the if statement, then finding it false, and skipping to the else {} now... I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the event `changeTitle` responds to?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: When is this function called?

Comment: When a button on my storyboard is pushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@IBAction func changeTitle(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    if (button.titleLabel?.text == "Title1") {
        button.setTitle("Title2", forState: .Normal)

    } else {
        button.setTitle("Title1", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! What I still don't understand is why it even went into the if clause, because I forgot the .text, so it should have been false.

Comment: It did go to the "else" clause because the "if" part was false.  Take your original code and put a couple of println() methods in.  Something like println("if") within the "if" branch and println("else") within the else branch.  That is what I did to diagnose it.  Alternatively just change the title in the else clause to something like "Title3".  I do think the API methods written by Apple can confuse.  You can setTitle without further .text chaining but to read the titleLabel text you need .text.